# Calling a method on object from it's class subclass

Tags: java, superclass

I am trying to call a method from the class `Weapon`, which is a subclass of `Item`. As you can see from the field I've declared the object `currentWeapon` as an object of Item, and in the `setCurrentWeapon` method I use `getClass()` method to check that the `Item` is really of subclass Weapon.

Is there a way that I can successfully call the methods from `Weapon` class on my Item object (which in reality is of Weapon class)?

`backpack` is an hashmap that contains `Item` objects. If I set `currentWeapon` as a `Weapon` in the field, the `Weapon` object won't be added to the `backpack`.

The method that fails to compile: 
(cannot find symbol -  method getMinDamage())

```
public int attack(Imperial currentEnemy) {
    int damage = Utils.random(currentWeapon.getMinDamage(), currentWeapon.getMaxDamage()+1);
    currentEnemy.changeHealth(-damage);
    return damage;
}
```

The field:

```
private Item currentWeapon;
```

Method for setting currentWeapon:

```
public boolean setCurrentWeapon(String itemToEquip) {
    if(useItem(itemToEquip) == true) {
        currentWeapon = backpack.get(itemToEquip.toLowerCase());
        if(currentWeapon.getClass() == Weapon.class) {
            System.out.println(getNick() + " has equipped " + currentWeapon.getName() + " as current weapon");
            equipped = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(itemToEquip + " is not a weapon");
            currentWeapon = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else System.out.println(itemToEquip + " is not owned by " + getNick());
    return false;
}
```

I hope this question wasn't too confusing, please give tips on how to clarify if this is  a problem

Comment: Your field is called 'currentWeapon' but you give it a type Item instead of Weapon... Whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: Perhaps using abstract methods..., the question is not very clear ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call

```
currentWeapon.getMinDamage()
```

`currentWeapon` has type `Item`.  It's run-time type is `Weapon`, but you're getting a compile-time error about it being the wrong type.  If you want the field to remain of type `Item`, you will need to cast it to a `Weapon` before calling that method, to tell the compiler that you expect it to really be of type `Weapon`:

```
((Weapon)currentWeapon).getMinDamage()
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer to my question. Very informative and the solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the type of the `Item` with `instanceof Weapon` then cast the `Item` to a `Weapon`.

A better design for your `Backpack` might be to make it a class that wraps different collections of different types of inventory.  For example you could have:

```
class Backpack {
    List<Weapon> weapons;
    List<Armor> armory;
    List<Provision> provisions;
    ...
}
```

Then overload an `add` method so items are added to the right collection.

That would give you the flexibility to loop through all of the collections if you need to treat all of the items in your backpack as generic `Item`s (for example if you need to get the total weight of your backpack), but still keep different types of `Item`s separate for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` to check whether or not something is an instance of a class. In this case, you could use:

```
Weapon a; Item b;
if(a instanceof Weapon) returns true
if(b instanceof Weapon) returns false
```

Then, you can simply cast it.

`instanceof` checks to see whether the object in its first argument is of the second argument's type, and can therefore be safely be cast the the type in its second argument. So, if an item is a weapon, it must be instantiated specifically as a weapon.

Therefore, `Weapon instanceof Item` would also be true.

The reason for the error in your code is that you're invoking a Weapon-only function on an Item; you first need to check to see if you can cast the Item to Weapon, then cast it.